# NestedScrollView with viewPager in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

Below is the code to handle the correct behaviour of my actionBar/toolbar/tabBar and below them the nestedScrollView with a ViewPager(webView). The ViewPager is basically a normal webView.

I am seeking to copy this exact behavior:

[image: https://cdn.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/android-tab-layout-view-pager-output.gif]

Everything works except my ViewPager can't be scrolled vertically at the same time as the toolBar being scrolled. When the viewPager is being scrolled the toolbar is static (in order to make the toolbar scroll aswell I need to manually scroll the toolbar-area but it does not get affected by the viewPager at all). I am not able to scroll both at the same time like the example above!

**My code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     tools:context=".ui.activity.FragmentContainer"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     >

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
                 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                     app:theme="@style/M.Toolbar"
                     app:popupTheme="@style/M.Toolbar.PopupTheme"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                     app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                     >
                 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

         <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
             android:id="@+id/tabs"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             app:tabMode="scrollable"
             android:visibility="gone"
             android:background="@color/background"
             app:background="@color/background"/>

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
         android:background="@android:color/transparent"
         android:fillViewport="true"
         >

     <com.m.ui.util.EdgeScrollViewPager
         android:id="@+id/viewpager"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@android:color/transparent"
         android:visibility="visible"
         >

     </com.m.ui.util.EdgeScrollViewPager>

     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In order to make my viewPager(webView) scrollable I added a new class which extends webView:

```
public class TouchyWebView extends WebView {

     public TouchyWebView(Context context) {
         super(context);
     }

     public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
    }

     public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
         super(context, attrs, defStyle);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
         requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
         return super.onTouchEvent(event);
     }
}
```

**My viewPager.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@android:color/white">

     <com.m.ui.base.TouchyWebView
         android:id="@+id/web_webview"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@android:color/transparent"
         android:visibility="visible" />

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/web_loadingview"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:visibility="gone"
         android:layout_gravity="center">

         <ProgressBar
             style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:indeterminate="true"
             android:visibility="visible"
             android:layout_gravity="center"/>
     </LinearLayout>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Regards

Comment: add this line to you  tabLayout app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>

Comment: Did not solve the problem. My viewPager is scrollable but the toolBar is static when you scroll the viewPager (I need to manually scroll the toolBar-area in order to make it move).

Comment: Did you find the solution? I need exact behaviour as in gif